# Slight discrepancy in left/right margins

Tags: margins, paper-size, geometry

This is what I'm using:

```
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,twoside=true,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=4cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
```

For some reasons, when I print out my document, there seems to be a slight 1-2mm discrepancy between odd and even pages, when I look through a single sheet (with a light in the background).

What I see is that the page on the other side is shifted by 1-2mm to the right, compared to the page I'm looking at.

What could possibly explain this?

Comment: A defect in the printer driver? I think it may happen if you print from Adobe Reader and leave "Fit to printable area" or "Shrink to printable area".

Comment: @egreg Yeah, I think you're right...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The printer driver of Adobe Reader has a rather "nice" feature. If I look at the page properties of a PDF document produced with `pdflatex`, the program says

```
20.998 x 29.697 cm
```

while with `pdfinfo` I get

```
595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
```

However, according to `bc`,

```
595.276*2.54/72 = 21.00001444444444444444
841.89*2.54/72  = 29.70000833333333333333
```

so it's not clear why the dimensions are different from 21 x 29.7 cm. If I change the units to points (Postscript big points), Adobe Reader says 595.3 x 841.9, so I'm really confused about the computations it does, which imply a *shorter* inch than the official one (2.5397cm, instead of 2.54cm).

Since the output format is set to A4, which at Adobe Reader's eyes is *different* from the stated document size, the program offers by default to "Fit to printable area" with a zoom to 93%, which is quite a bizarre figure, since the document is *smaller* than the paper, at Reader's eyes, not larger.

So, **always watch out for the printing options** and remember to choose "None" from the "Page Scaling" pop up menu.

---

Preview for Mac OS X has exactly the same problem; here is a snapshot of what I get when asking to print something:

[image]

Where it's seen that the document will be slightly scaled down. If I choose the "Scale" option with 100% in the box, the result is correctly printed.

Note that [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I actually printed this with Preview on the Mac. But it's possible that it makes similar discrepancies as Adobe Reader. Do you have access to a Mac?

Comment: @MayGodBlessKnuth I don't think so; it may depend on the printer. Right now I can't access a printer, unfortunately.

Comment: @MayGodBlessKnuth I've tried with Preview and it has similar behavior as Adobe Reader. :( But a fix is easy.