# Shift Odd Page in Duplex Print

Tags: margins, double-sided, printing

This is more a printer problem, but I have no way to solve it on the printer side.

When printing a two sided document, the sides do not match vertically. That means for example the line of `\pagestyle{fancy}` is not continuous from the left to the right page but shifted by 2 mm (0.08 inches). Is there a way take this into account when generating the file?

`\addtolength{\voffset}{-2mm}` shifts all pages, not only the e.g. odd ones.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2mm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you look at this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79568/slight-discrepancy-in-left-right-margins

Comment: @egreg: yes, but it is definitely a problem on the printer side. It happens to all prints; not only PDF's. I think it is a general problem of printers when they turn the page.

Comment: Indeed it can be. It was something to attempt, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example, the page can be shifted by moving the output box right before the page is shipped out:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \edef\mytemp{%
      \ht\AtBeginShipoutBox=\the\ht\AtBeginShipoutBox\relax
      \dp\AtBeginShipoutBox=\the\dp\AtBeginShipoutBox\relax
    }%
    \sbox\AtBeginShipoutBox{%
      \raisebox{-1in}{\usebox\AtBeginShipoutBox}%
    }%
    \mytemp
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In case of pdfTeX in PDF mode, alternatively `\pdfvorigin` could be changed inside `\AtBeginShipout`.