# Incorrect size in printed pdf document

Tags: pdftex, texlive, dvipdfmx

My setup: TL2014, packaged with Debian 8.

I'm struggling with a serious problem, which started to bother me when I tried to get margins right in a printed document. After reading the following threads

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20081218052428/http://www.codecomments.com/Tex/message784423.html
http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2004-April/000485.html
http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2004-April/000487.html
http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2006-January/009735.html
http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2006-May/022359.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/xJQ2t2_OfSs
```

and doing a lot of experiments, I came to realize that it was not my misunderstanding of how margins must be set, but a more generic problem of wrong sizes. So, I boiled the issue down to this simple test.tex:

```
\nopagenumbers
\hrule width 100mm
\bye
```

```
$ sudo paperconfig -p a4
```

```
$ tex test.tex
$ dvips test.dvi
$ dvipdfmx test.dvi
```

Now print `test.ps` and `test.pdf`
Printed `test.ps` gives rule of 100mm.
Printed `test.pdf` gives rule of 91.5mm on all of 3 printers, which I tried.

NOTE: I also get the same 91.5mm on printed document, prepared with pdftex.

Then open `test.pdf` in viewer (I used acroread), adjust zoom to match physical paper size, and put printed `test.ps` on monitor screen - they overlap perfectly, which is not the case for printed `test.pdf`

Let's generate `test2.pdf` with some options (values are empirical):

```
$ dvipdfmx -m 1.09 -x 0.72in -y 0.55in -o test2.pdf test.dvi
```

Printed `test2.pdf` gives rule of 100mm.
Printed `test2.pdf` overlaps perfectly with displayed `test.pdf` on monitor screen, but displayed `test2.pdf` differs from displayed `test.pdf`

**EDIT:**
Why is pdf document printed with incorrect sizes?

Comment: By default, Adobe Reader shrinks A4 paper at 92%, when printing, unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79568/slight-discrepancy-in-left-right-margins However, I checked with my version of Adobe Reader (on Mac OS X) and it has not the issue any more. I'll try with Debian.

Comment: @egreg I printed from atril. I used acroread only to set variable zoom when checking the overlay on monitor screen (atril only has fixed zoom levels).

Comment: It seems to be a very similar problem anyhow.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, atril is to blame: File->Print->Page Handling. By default "Page Scaling" is "Shrink to Printable Area". Change it to "None" and it prints correctly. I don't believe that a user who simply wants to print a document has to know that he must change this option! Anyway, are there any specific reasons that the developers have chosen exactly _this_ default value, and not any other? Would you advise to contact the developers of atril?

Comment: If you see in my answer to the question I linked, the same happens with Preview on Mac OS X. I think Adobe has fixed it in newer versions of Reader, possibly the same mistake has been made by `atril`.

Comment: @egreg Anyhow, why do the options "Shrink to Printable Area" and "Fit to Printable Area" mess with my document? My document is perfectly legitimate. I have large enough margins, which don't violate the "Printable Area".

Comment: It's something you should ask somewhere else, I'm afraid.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko -- i'm sure this has trapped every user of adobe reader in the world, and wasted a forest worth of paper.  maybe an accusation that adobe is not being environmentally friendly would have some effect.

Comment: I suspect they were just making their product idiot proof.  Older printers get upset when you try to print outside the printable area.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by the choice of pdf viewer