# How to set margins and page size in pdfLaTeX without geometry?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, geometry, paper-size

What is the `TeX` equivalent of

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm, 
            paperheight=15cm,
            margin=0mm,
            bottom=1mm]{geometry}
```

?

I know nothing in `TeX` and so far, I am playing with expressions such as

```
\newlength{\initialVerticalHeight}
\setlength{\initialVerticalHeight}{5cm}

\newlength{\bottomMargin}
\setlength{\bottomMargin}{1mm}

\global\setlength\paperheight\initialVerticalHeight%
\global\setlength\pdfpageheight\initialVerticalHeight%
\global\setlength\textheight{\dimexpr\paperheight-\bottomMargin}%
```

but I can't find the equivalent of `left`(margin) and `top`(margin).

Is it very complicated? I'm trying to avoid using `geometry` package because I'm doing tricky things and want to have a clear understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Btw, do you mean TeX or LaTeX?

Comment: When I tried to figure it out for myself, I used links listed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241575/incorrect-size-in-printed-pdf-document You may use that as a starting point. Also search this forum by `voffset`, `hoffset`, `hsize`, `vsize`; if you use pdftex, look also into pdftexmagfix.tex

Comment: Even better, look into the source of *OPmac* package, or use it directly.

Comment: @Bernard I need to understand how things work. I don't know if this is TeX or LaTeX. What I mean is how can I achieve the same result with more basic tools. What I need to do ultimately is beyond the capabilities of `geometry`.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253357/71471

Comment: is this a set up you need for a LaTeX document, but with [pdf]TeX primitives?

Comment: @Louie Yes, kind of.

Comment: Well, then Touhami's  answer looks reasonable, and Igor's is impracticable. By the way, \setlength is LaTeX, not Plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\bottomMargin}
\setlength{\bottomMargin}{1mm}

% paper size
\setlength{\paperwidth}{10cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{15cm}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
% horizontal dimensions
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
% vertical dimension
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
%\setlength{\topskip}{10pt}   if you are about new class
%\setlength\footskip{30pt} if you want a footer, here no place for footer
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\bottomMargin}



\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Latex format set `\topskip=10pt` standard class set it  `10pt, 11pt ,12pt`. It should never be set `0pt`

**Note** number of lines in the page is also factor in the text height or the bottom magin.